Should I attach the toilet flange to the floating sub-floor, or through that into the cement
I’ve had to repair the floor around the toilet, but did not replace the entire floor.  The pipe was originally set into the floor after the original basement installation, and the concrete is pretty uneven.  The sub-floor is Dricore (Dricore Home Page), with DMX (DMX Home Page) underlayment on top, which I chose to act also as a spacer to get a height match.  Should I screw the toilet flange to the Dricore sub-floor, or through into the cement?

Never heard of a floating subfloor before.  I would attach the flange to concrete, if you have it.

Just going on a gut feeling so not posting as an answer, but I assume the waste pipe goes through the concrete and is somewhat anchored in that? If so, it would make sense to me to also anchor the flange to the concrete to reduce the chance of movement between the flange and the pipe it's attached to.

I’ve added some images, so you guys can see what I’m dealing with.  I’m also thinking that the concrete poured when the pipe was put in might be suspect, so I’m  loathe to drill it.  A failed flange being the better option compared to a cracked floor.

In my area of the country the majority of homes are built on cement slabs. In these instances toilet flanges are anchored into the concrete.
In practical terms the screws to anchor into the Dricore would be fairly short and not add much stability.  I would anchor into the cement, but be careful to not over tighten.

The Dricore will also require the use of a spacer to close the void, they are available in 1/2" and 3/4" heights. Seal it to the mounted flange wil poly caulk, then the wax ring. My apologies for adding to your answer RD, but your answer is the right one.


I thought I’d post the results of all my research, including everyone here’s terrific advice - even if I went another way ;-)
The image shows the test I made screwing the #14 screw through what I have as a floating floor.  So that’s 12mm (1/2 in) laminate on DMX moisture barrier as a spacer on Dricore.  The screw does not penetrate the cement under the Dricore.
I found another clue in a YouTube video talking about why we don’t use wooden wedges under toilets:  the wood will deform under the weight of the toilet.  Laminate flooring is made of dust, and epoxy, and Dricore is OSB made with waterproof glue.  I feel that what I’ve come up with should hold as long as the seal does.
None of the manufacturer instructions talk about this issue, but they all say to screw the flange to the floor.  All the compensation mechanisms compensate for a flange that’s too low.  i.e. a cutout was made the size of the flange, or larger, and the surface in the cutout sits significantly below the level of the floor surface.  I cut all the components to be as snug to the waste pipe as possible, so the flange sits on top of the floor, per manufacturer instructions.
I ended up using an Oatey screw in flange, which has a long enough throat to get past the damage I found to the inside surfaces of the waste pipe near the top where the previous worker had scarred it with a saw.
Into that I put a ‘Better than Wax’ seal so that, if there’s a problem, I can lift the toilet to adjust/fix it without too much fuss.
I have left off sealing in the base of the toilet until I’m convinced I’ve got the job done.
The floor is so wavy that the gap at the front of the toilet is half an inch, where the back of the toilet is a hair above the floor.  A 12mm (1/2 in) laminate scrap cut to match the profile of the toilet base solved the gap, and a couple of toilet shims fixed the rest.
It’s been a week since it was in use again, and so far, so good.
Thank you again for your advice.  It was very helpful.

Using the concrete for support is probably better but given your reluctance, if you choose not to: screwing to a thin subfloor that is actually floating is a bad idea.  Make a spacer ring to fit around the flange so there is no empty space under the sub floor, no ribs, no dimples. Glue that to the floor and glue the subfloor to the ring.  Do the same to the spacers and subfloor in the general area of the toilet .. nothing should be actually floating.  Then use screws the maximum possible length to screw the flange down to the subfloor and spacer.
